# Update Amazon RDS for MySQL database instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, operating-system, amazon-rds, upgrade, database-replication

How to apply a new operating system (OS) update with critical security fixes update for Amazon RDS for MySQL database instance with little/no downtime?

In my case, I have the following database with multi-AZ to be update

```
in US-EAST-1 Region:
MySQL-cad-57-replica
MySQL-cad-57-rds
cad-DB-prod
```

Can someone guide what should be the best strategy to reduce the downtime? and Is there a way to know how much downtime would be applied?

Comment: What specific 'update' are you wanting to apply?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) is a **fully-managed service**. You do not have any access to the operating system or database installation. AWS is fully responsible for maintaining the infrastructure (In fact, there is no way to even know what Operating System is being used!)

You can, however, control updates to the **database engine**. You can configure Amazon RDS to automatically perform minor updates during a specified maintenance window. Major updates require you to specifically request the update.

See: [Upgrading a DB instance engine version - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html)

During such updates, there will be some downtime. You can avoid the downtime by using [High availability (Multi-AZ) for Amazon RDS - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html), which **deploys two database servers**. While one server is being updated, the other server will service requests. The active server will then be switched. There is only momentary downtime and any current connections to the database will be closed.

Comment: Thanks, @John Rotenstein, Is there a way to know how much downtime would be applied?

Comment: Ah! This article suggests that a major upgrade must be done to both the Primary and Secondary servers simultaneously so there would be downtime: [Minimize downtime during required Amazon RDS maintenance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-required-maintenance/)